# Add Sessions Percentage Bar Column When Embedding Google Analytic Table Chart

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytic dashboard, I found that the table chart for language, Country, City, etc got a column for sessions percentage.

[image: Google Analytic Screenshot for table with session percentage]

How to add the column to my website ? Currently only total sessions column is being shown

```
var userSessionChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
        "dimensions": "ga:language",
        "metrics": 'ga:sessions',
        "start-date": start_date,
        "end-date": end_date
    },
    chart: {
        container: 'user-session-container',
        type: 'TABLE',
        options: {
            width: '100%'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by sessions percentage (new sessions ?) but in general you will find all available dimensions and metrics here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#mode=api

Comment: hi @EikePierstorff, I've added a picture of the result that I want to achieve, thanks before